# SQL Max Value But Also Displaying Values From Other Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have data being pulled from a few different tables to give me the below sample data.  The sample data is just showing one OrderID for simplicity.  What I need to do is get the line with the max price for the OrderID, but I also need to see the other ID's associated with that specific line, as can be seen in the desired result table below.  Is there any way I can achieve this?

I'm creating a view in SQL of this data, and if it's possible I'd like to do it all in one view.

**Current Code**

```
SELECT        Items.OrderID, Items.ItemID, Items.Code, Price.Price
FROM            Items LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Codes ON Items.Code = Codes.Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ItemCategories ON Codes.CategoryID = ItemCategories.CategoryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Price ON Codes.CodeGrouping = Price.CodeGrouping
WHERE        (YEAR(Items.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) OR
                         YEAR(Items.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1) AND (ItemCategories.CategoryID = 1) AND (Items.OrderID_Status = 3)
```

**Sample Data**

```
OrderID     ItemID     Code     Price
--------------------------------------
454646      429264     12121    833
454646      429677     6116     1
454646      431168     194      719
454646      431248     6078     1
454646      432023     455      1030
```

**Desired Result**

```
OrderID     ItemID     Code     Max_Price
-----------------------------------------------------
454646      432023     455      1030
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the query you run to fetch thise result?

Comment: Current code now added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `row_number()`, because it is easy to integrate it in an existing query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by orderid order by price desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

In your original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT        
        i.OrderID, 
        i.ItemID, 
        i.Code, 
        p.Price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.OrderID ORDER BY p.Price DESC) rn
    FROM Items i
    LEFT JOIN Codes c           ON i.Code = c.Code 
    LEFT JOIN ItemCategories ic ON c.CategoryID = ic.CategoryID 
    LEFT JOIN Price p           ON c.CodeGrouping = p.CodeGrouping
    WHERE
        i.Date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, 1, 1)
        AND i.Date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1)
        AND ic.CategoryID IN (1, 3)
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Note that I changed the query a little:

- the filtering on the dates can be optimized - do not apply date functions on the date columns (it precludes an existing index on the column)
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read

Comment: Thanks GMB, how would I add that to my code in my original post?

Comment: You are a life saver!  That worked flawlessly.  Thanks for the tips too.